# Valgrind reports no memory leak despite a huge heap being allocated

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-leaks

I don't have a leak, I actually have a drain so it should be easy to find, but I can't seem to do it.

I have an openGL program running and doing a `glReadPixels` to a `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object`, and that is running fine. My problem is on the program reading the shared memory (actually into an openGL texture of another openGL program) that is permenently increasing memory usage...

I'm trying to fix this, but don't quite understand where the problem is.

Valgrind reports no leak:

```
==6697== HEAP SUMMARY:  
==6697== in use at exit: 116 bytes in 3 blocks  
==6697== total heap usage: 35,975 allocs, 35,972 frees, 2,784,987,994 bytes allocated  
==6697==   
==6697== LEAK SUMMARY:  
==6697== definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==6697== indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==6697== possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==6697== still reachable: 116 bytes in 3 blocks  
==6697== suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

But what puzzles me is the heap usag, the way i'm using the shared memory is inside function display:

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;  
void display(void)  
{  
/* setup texture*/  
GLuint textureID;  
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);  
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);  
shared_memory_object shm (open_only,"shared",read_only);  
mapped_region region(shm, read_only);  
char *mem = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());  
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA, 720, 576, 0,  GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,(GLvoid*)mem);
```

The allocated shared memory is only 1658880 bytes, so why does it keep growing?

Can anyone help me getting on the right track with this? Is there any way I can free the variables? Everything I've tried has ended up in a segfault.

edit:
the complete code for my test is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>    
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>   
#include <thread>       
#include <chrono>    
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::interprocess;


void display(void)
    {
    /* setup texture*/
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    /*grab data from shared memory*/
    shared_memory_object shm (open_only,"partilha",read_only);
    mapped_region region(shm, read_only);
    char *mem = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
    /*----------------------------------*/
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA, 720, 576, 0, GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,(GLvoid*)mem);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f (1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush ();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    }


void init (void)
    {
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (720, 576);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("output");
    init ();
    while (true)
        {
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutMainLoopEvent();        
        this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

So, actually I'm using display function 60 times a second... and that is what is summing up memory, but shoudn't it be destroyed at the end of the function? How can I destroy it? Thanks

Comment: For what I can see, the memory is bound to the object `region` which is destroyed at the end of the program which does explain why there is no leak.
So when it comes to the rest of the problem, we probably need to know what else you're doing in your program. Is `display` called only once? How do you initialize your variables?

Comment: You're creating a new texture with a `glGenTextures()` call in `display()`. Are you deleting this texture anywhere?

Comment: A shared memory segment is not (a|the) heap and AFAIK valgrind will not track it.

Comment: thank you all for your help... I see now that I actually don't destroy region anyware... and probably that sums up fast... but how can I destroy it? free(region) does not work... Thanks... (sorry for such basic question).   I edited my post to include the rest of the code on this project

Comment: I think I got it... Reto Koradi had it right... I needed to delete the texture after using it...I added a   glDeleteTextures(1, &textureID); at the end of the display function and that did it... Thanks for all the help!